# MongoD: How to update specific field of a document in a collection?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection of **jobs** in MongoDB and in this collection there is a field in the documents named as appliedUser. I want to update this field when a new user applies for this job.So basically this field stores the id's of all the users who are applying for this job.

I am using findOneAndUpdate() function but not able to do it.

```
Job.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set: { appliedUser: 
req.user.id } }, function(err, job) {
    console.log(job);
})
```

and here is my Schema:

```
const jobSchema = new Schema({
date: { type: Date, default: Date() },
expirydate: { type: Date, required: true },
name: { type: String, required: true },
companydetails: { type: String, required: true },
address: { type: String, required: true },
role: { type: String, required: true },
city: { type: String, required: true },
minsalary: { type: Number, required: true },
maxsalary: { type: Number, required: true },
skills: { type: Array, required: true },
minex: { type: Number, required: true },
appliedUser: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users', unique: 
true }],
user: { type: String, required: true }

})
```

The array of the document is not updating. I am not able to find the errors.

Answer (score 5):

Look like what you need is [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/). Example:

```
Job.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $addToSet: { appliedUser:  req.user.id } }, function(err, job) {
  console.log(job);
})
```

Comment: Is there any error? Or the id to add is already in the array? Can you log the `req.params.id` and `req.user.id` to check all is right

Comment: Neither ID is already in Array,nor there is any error. It's working for the first array in collection but not working for others

Comment: You need to pass new:true to the option so it will return the updated doc in the callback